# How to keep the dictionary in order after zipping

Tags: python

Dictionary keeps the order correctly when there are around 1,2 or 3 elements only

```
>>> a = ["dorian", "strawberry", "apple"]
>>> b = ["sweet", "delicious", "tasty"]
>>> c = dict(zip(a, b))
>>> c
{'dorian': 'sweet', 'strawberry': 'delicious', 'apple': 'tasty'}
```

But when there are over 3 elements, the order is broken

```
>>> a = ["dorian", "strawberry", "apple", "coconut"]
>>> b = ["sweet", "delicious", "tasty", "yum"]
>>> c = dict(zip(a, b))
>>> c
{'strawberry': 'delicious', 'coconut': 'yum', 'dorian': 'sweet', 'apple': 'tasty'}
```

Could anyone please explain why it happens that way ? thanks

Comment: dictionaries don't preserve order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python dictionaries don't maintain any order, you should use [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for that.

```
In [7]: from collections import OrderedDict as od

In [8]: a = ["dorian", "strawberry", "apple"]

In [9]: b = ["sweet", "delicious", "tasty"]

In [10]: dic=od(zip(a,b))

In [11]: dic
Out[11]: OrderedDict([('dorian', 'sweet'), ('strawberry', 'delicious'), ('apple', 'tasty')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Python [`dict`s are unordered](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

```
from collections import OrderedDict as odict

# ...
c = odict(zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are Map Data Structures. You can never linear guarantee order. Sacrificing this you gain speed in the underlying implementation.

Comment: I'm half tempted to -1 this one because it's very much possible to make ordering guarantees in a map, without sacrificing all that much speed. (I.e. if you keep the values in a doubly linked list you can maintain order with constant overhead on insertion/deletion. Or in a tree to have log(n) overhead and keep the dictionary sorted by key or value.)